How to check element visibility in Flutter app test automation using JavaScript WebDriverIO framework?
I am automating a Flutter app using the JavaScript WebDriverIO framework.
However, I am unable to find an implemented method for checking if an element is visible. While there is an await method available for each element that waits for the element to be present, I am unsure if it can be used to determine element visibility.
Is there a way to check element visibility in Flutter app automation with JavaScript WebDriverIO, or is there an alternative approach to achieve this?
await driver.elementClick(button)

